# Does WPF use INotifyPropertyChanging

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I wonder if WPF infrastructure utilizes `INotifyPropertyChanging` event on binding or its developers have plans to do it in future releases. Appreciate any link to respective information

**Edit:**

The idea behind my question was that I was recently being unable to cancel `SelectionChanged` event in `DataGrid`. Being bound to something like `MySelectedProperty` in my view-model it listens (I hope) to `PropertyChanged("MySelectedProperty")` to actually select different row. So I wonder why couldn't it listen to `PropertyChanging("MySelectedProperty")` to cancel the selection when I set `Cancel` to `true`

Comment: have a look here to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995893/why-doesnt-anyone-use-the-inotifypropertychanging

Comment: from what I gather there is only PropertyChanged but alot of work arounds if you wanted to record the change