# Label Content does not change with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm currently having problems with my label content being updated. Is there something I'm missing here to have it update on `Current_Plan` property update? See below for implementation:

In my xaml code I have a Label called `LabelProductionPlan` set up like the following:

```
   <Label x:Name="LabelProductionPlan" 
          Content="{Binding Current_Plan.ProductionPlanName, 
                            Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

In my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file, the setup is as follows:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private FrontEndManager FEM;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;


            FEM = new FrontEndManager
            {
                Current_Plan = new ProductionPlanModel
                {

                }

            };

            LabelProductionPlan.DataContext = FEM;
        }}
```

The `FrontEndManager` is setup with the following [Fody feature](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanging) to implement PropertyChanging:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanging]
public class FrontEndManager
{
    public ProductionPlanModel Current_Plan { get; set; }
}
```

With the `ProductionPlanModel` implemented as well with `PropertyChanging`:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanging]
public class ProductionPlanModel
{
    public string ProductionPlanName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you're using the wrong Fody tool - you want Fody.PropertyChanged

Comment: I've just found an actual use case for INotifyPropertyChanging other than the ugly "throw an exception to stop a property setter" - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41472332/967885

Comment: @Peregrine You are right! Would you like to submit that so I can accept your answer? Thank you so much for catching that!

Answer (score -1):

The event you are using, *changing* is not used by most dependency properties, such as the `Content` you have bound to in a `Label`. You need to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` event which supplies a notification when the value fully changes and can be used. As mentioned it appears you need to use `Fody.PropertyChanged` instead.